Copy or Sync all the branches from one Org Repo to another org with same repo
I have written the powershell script which will sync or copy the repo from one org to another org, but currently this script is sync only master branch, but not all the branches.
Below is the Code
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Sync the Repo one from Org to another Org.
 
.DESCRIPTION
    Repo or Detla sync of entire repo from Org to another org 
    using Powershell script.
#>
 
#Clear Console
Clear-Host
 
# Delete the Old Destination Folder
$Path = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(API_Repo)\"
if (Test-Path $Path -PathType Container) {
    # Get all files in the folder
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path
    # Loop through each file and delete it
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        Remove-Item $file.FullName -Force
        Write-Output "Deleted: $($file.Name)"
        }
}
 
#Source URL to fetch the Repo
$Sourceurl = "https://$(SourceOrg):$(PAT)@dev.azure.com/$(SourceOrg)/$(URLSourceProject)/_git/$(API_Repo)"
 
#Destination URL to push the Repo
$DestinationURL = "https://$(DestinationOrg):$(PAT)@dev.azure.com/$(DestinationOrg)/$(DestinationProject)/_git/$(API_Repo)"
 
#Set Location for current folder
Set-Location "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
Write-Output "***** Cloning the Source URL*****"
git clone $Sourceurl
 
#Set Location to get the latest repo from source
Write-Output "Source Project: $(API_Repo)"
Set-Location "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(API_Repo)\"
Write-Output "*****Git removing remote origin****"
 
#Git Commands to fetch and push the code
git remote rm origin
 
Write-Output "*****Git remote add****"
git remote add --mirror=fetch origin $DestinationURL
 
Write-Output "*****Git fetch origin****"
git fetch $sourceURL
 
Write-Output "*****Git push to Global Repos****"
git push origin --all -f

I have modified the line from git fetch $sourceURL to git fetch origin to fetch all the branches in repo, but when i run the pipeline i am seeing this warning or error.

fatal: refusing to fetch into branch 'refs/heads/master' checked out at '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Polydone.Api'


While this question is legitimate here, honestly it would probably get answered better and faster on https://stackoverflow.com/ where for sure some programmers have already encountered such a situation

This is already answered on Stack overflow. I don't want to duplicate answers, so here are some links: link1 (5184 upvotes for the accepted answer), link2 (67 upvotes), link3 (nice discussion). Did one of them work for you?
